# How to prevent ORA-00900 error when running Oracle SQL Developer query using pandas.read_sql()?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is an example of a SQL Developer query I'd like to run from Python.

```
sqlQuery = """
DEFINE a = 1
DEFINE b = 2

select &&a + &&b from dual
"""
result = pandas.read_sql(sql=sqlQuery, con=Oracle_Connection)
```

This query works when I run it inside of SQL Developer, however when I run the above code in Python, I get the following error: `'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'`. Is there an easy fix I can make to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> DEFINE a = 1
> DEFINE b = 2
> ```

DEFINE is a command of SQL*Plus or SQLDeveloper, that is not SQL command.
You need to use bind variables instead:

```
select :a + :b from dual;
```

Full example:

```
sqlQuery = """
select :a + :b from dual
"""
result = pandas.read_sql(sql=sqlQuery, con=Oracle_Connection, params={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```